# Role assignment using SCIM

Tags: okta, scim

How does one assign application roles (like USER, MANAGER, ADMIN) through SCIM? Okta is managing the user directory and the application is currently creating, updating and deactivating users when the users are altered in Okta.

It does not seem obvious to me how I could use the SCIM standard to manage which part of the organization, and which role, each user should have. I imagined that I could perhaps use Groups for that, but there is not much to use in a group as a reference.

My initial take was to create groups named as "Department 1 - manager", "Department 2 - manager", "Department 2 - user" and so on. But there is no slug or id or anything other than the group name to reference to, once in the application. This made me wonder if this was really a good idea.

How does one usually do this?

Answer (score 1):

You could either base it of the group names as you mention, or you could add and map departments and roles as custom attributes in Okta and add them to your SCIM.